# Mlab Contains Query

Tags: android, mongodb, httprequest, retrofit2, mlab

Is it possible to use a like/contains query in mLab?
I have json data like so on the server https://mlab.com/:

`"County": "Kildare, Laois, Carlow"`

I can query the dataset to return all where trails = County Kildare:

`@GET("databases/walks/collections/walks")
    Call<List<Trail>> byCounty (@Query("q") String county,@Query("apiKey") String apiKey);`

The parameter "q" contains: `q={"County": "Kildare"}`

But that only select data that match the following :

```
"County": "Kildare"
```

Is there an Mlab query that has the same function as Contains in MongoDB or Like in SQL. So i can search the county field if it contains "Kildare".

Or even how to do it in A HTTP request, i might be able to use it within the `q={ }`. 
Ive tried using `q={"County":"/.*Kildare.*/"}`

Thank You.

Comment: `Is there a retrofit query that has the same function as Contains in MongoDB or Like in SQL` - retrofit is not a database

Comment: retrofit has no influence on the server's capabilities of serving data..

Comment: thanks changed the question title

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `q` parameter in the mLab Data API is just a MongoDB query document. You can use any [MongoDB operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) like you would normally in a MongoDB query document.

MongoDB doesn't have a `$contains` operator. But if you're searching for text in a string, you can use the `$regex` or `$text` operator. See the [documentation for `$regex`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) and the [documentation for `$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) to learn more.

To use `$regex`, try this as the `q` parameter:

```
q={"County": {"$regex": "Kildare"}}
```

To use `$text`, first build a text index on the County field. You can do this on the mLab management portal ([instructions in the documentation](http://docs.mlab.com/indexing/#index-management)) or run this command on the mongo shell:

```
db.walks.createIndex({ County: "text" })
```

You can then try this as the `q` parameter:

```
q={"$text": {"$search": "Kildare"}}
```

**Important Note:** `$regex` and `$text` can be extremely inefficient operations. It may be much more efficient and easier for you to restructure your data model. Rather than having a list of counties in a string, perhaps have them in an array like so:

```
"County": ["Kildare", "Laois", "Carlow"]
```

Then to search for all documents that contain Kildare in their County array, you can simply use this query:

```
q={"County": "Kildare"}
```

This may be a better option for you than using `$regex` or `$text`.